# Extract CVE from a text column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching, extract, cve

I need to extract a CVE from a text column. The format is `CVE-yyyy-xxxxx`.

The year(`yyyy`) is variable, and the `x`’s will change per CVE - can be 1 to 6 digits. Sometimes the CVE is enclosed in `()`, sometimes followed by `:`

The column is like:

```
the vulnerability name (CVE-2019-0215) 
the vulnerability name (CVE-2019-0290) extra words 
the vulnerability name CVE-2018-23314: blah blah
```

Expected Output in a new column:

```
CVE-2019-0215
CVE-2019-0290
CVE 2018-23314
```

Comment: Have you got some actual sample data with expected results just to see what you are trying? Do you know about the `SUBSTRING()` function? >> `SELECT SUBSTRING(<input>, <pattern>) as NewCol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is useful to layout the problem through sample data, and the expected result (ps: for this please learn some stackoverflow [format capability](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)).

**sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   sourcecol VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(sourcecol) VALUES ('the vulnerability name (CVE-2019-0215)');
INSERT INTO mytable(sourcecol) VALUES ('the vulnerability name (CVE-2019-0290) extra words');
INSERT INTO mytable(sourcecol) VALUES ('the vulnerability name CVE-2018-23314: blah blah');
```

**query: using regex pattern in substring function**

```
select substring(sourcecol from '(CVE-[0-9]{1,6}-[0-9]{1,6})+')
from mytable
```

this regex "pattern" looks for the string starting with "CVE-" followed by 1 to 6 digits followed by "-" followed by 1 to 6 digits

**result**

```
+----------------+
|   substring    |
+----------------+
| CVE-2019-0215  |
| CVE-2019-0290  |
| CVE-2018-23314 |
+----------------+
```

see this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8eda9cd9ac8ae2b30cd2501625e5c766)

Comment: Thank you very much helping and also for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about the standard CVE format, extracting the year can easily be done using substring() with a regular expression:

```
substring('CVE-2022-1552' from 'CVE-([0-9]{4})-[0-9]+')
```

returns `2022`

`substring()` will return the first matching group, so the regex "describes" the whole pattern and by using a capturing group for the year, only that will be returned.

If you need to match other formats, you need to adjust the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Returns the first valid CVE (according to your definition) in the string:

```
SELECT substring(col1, 'CVE-[12]\d{3}-\d{1,6}') AS cve
FROM  tbl;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=611b139311090c5a83acb856f0b68f3b)*

The first CVE was issued 1999, so the year can start with *1* or *2*.

The official definition of a [CVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures) allows at least 4 digits and as many digits as needed for the serial number, so:

```
SELECT substring(col1, 'CVE-[12]\d{3}-\d{4,}') AS cve
FROM  tbl;
```

Details for [regular expressions in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).